# Progress bar percentage

Tags: c#, progress

Could someone please tell me how I can get the correct percentage progress figure? I'm getting values going above 100% - Can't seem to get my head around it.

Thanks

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        string[] strArray = txtSource.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Int32 i = 0;

        foreach (string item in strArray)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(250);

            string returnMessage = DoAction(item).Replace(nl,"");
            i++;

            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i, item + " ..." + returnMessage);                
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblProgress.Text = "Progress: " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "% complete, processing: " + e.UserState.ToString();
        txtResults.Text += "Processing " + e.UserState.ToString() + nl;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnRun.Enabled = true;
        lblProgress.Text = "Action completed!";            
    }
```

Comment: if you have more than 100 strings in the array then `i` will exceed 100. do something like `i / strArray.Length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're increasing `i` on each iteration on `strArray`, it is incorrect to use `i` as percent of execution here just because it will be exact percent of execution if and only if your array contains 100 items:

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i, item + " ..." + returnMessage);
```

You can simply use `(100 * i) / strArray.Length` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `i/(double)strArray.Length` or will it automatically switch to float division?

Comment: Dawnkeeper is correct. You should force it to not use integer division.    
    
Or you could go for (100*i)/strArray.Length if you want to have an int between 0-100

Comment: @JakobOlsen, oh you're right, thank you. I missed the fact that percentage should be int from 0 to 100. Also because of this fact there is no need to use double division - integer one is pretty enough. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @NadimAJ you actually don't need double. `(100 * i) / strArray.Length` is enough.

Comment: The progress percentage value is correct but the progress bar doesn't reach the end, i.e. it feels it's complete when the bar is around 75% full for 130 items in the array. When and where do I set the progress bar maxsize, if that is indeed the correct property?

Comment: Sorry, was over engeering. Worked it out. You don't need to specify a max size!

Answer (score 0):

its because you have more than 100 items in your `strArray`.
Do it this way-

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    string[] strArray = txtSource.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    Int32 i = 0;
    int iLength = strArray.Length;
    foreach (string item in strArray)
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(250);

        string returnMessage = DoAction(item).Replace(nl,"");
        i++;

        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i/iLength , item + " ..." + returnMessage);                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i, item + " ..." + returnMessage);` to `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i / strArray.Length , item + " ..." + returnMessage);`